# App Facebook Page

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook page for my app, however it still says "Create Facebook Page" at the bottom of my Facebook App settings.  If I click that can I connect my current page to my app page?

Comment: I don't want to do something that can't be undone.

Comment: you can create another application and another page just for test :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not connect your current Fan/Product Page with your Application,
it will create a new, dedicated page for your Application.